# Calling specific cells in the same column (using dplyr?)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with character and numeric data. I would like to use dplyr to create a summary grouped by time points and trials generating the following:

1. averages
2. standard deviations
3. variation
4. ***ratio between time points***

   (etc etc)

I feel like all of this could be done in the dplyr pipe, but I am struggling to make a ratio of averages between time points within trials.

I fully admit that I may be carrying around a hammer looking for nails, so please feel free to recommend solutions that utilize other packages or functions, but ideally I'd like simple/straight forward code for ease of use by multiple collaborators.

```
library(dplyr)

# creating an example DF 
num <- runif(100, 50, 3200)
smpl <- 1:100
df <- data.frame( num, smpl)
df$time <- "time1"
df$time[seq(2,100,2)] <- "time2"
df$trial <- "a"
df$trial[26:50] <- "b"
df$trial[51:75] <- "c"
df$trial[75:100] <- "d"

# using the magic of pipelines to calculate useful things
df1 <- df %>% 
group_by(time, trial) %>% 
summarise(avg = mean(num), 
var = var(num),
stdev = sd(num))
```

I'd love to get **[the ratio time2/time1 of the avg for each trial]** included in this block above, but I don't know how to call "avg" specifically by "time1" vs "time2" within the pipe.

From here on, nothing does quite what I'm hoping for...

```
df1 <- df1[with(df1,order(trial,time)),] 
# this better ressembles my actual DF structure,
# so reordering it will make some of my next attempts to solve this make more sense
```

I tried to use the fact that 'every other line' is different (this is not ideal because each df will have a different number of rows, so I will either introduce NAs or it will require constantly change these #'s (or writing a function to constantly change them))

```
tm2 <- data.frame(x=df1$avg[seq(2,4,2)])
tm1 <- data.frame(x=df1$avg[seq(1,3,2)])
```

so minimally, this is the ratio I'd like included in the df, but tied to the avg & trial columns:

```
tm2/tm1
```

It doesn't matter to me 'which' time row this ratio ends up in, so long as it is consistent across all the trials (so if a column of ratios has "blank" for every "time1" and "value" for every "time2", that's fine).

```
# I added in a separate column to allow 'match' later
tm1$time <- "time1"
tm2$time <- "time1"  # to keep them all 'in row'
df1$avg_tm1 <- tm1$x[match(df1$time, tm1$time)]
df1$avg_tm2 <- tm2$x[match(df1$time, tm2$time)]
```

but this fails to match by 'trial' also, since that info is lost in this new tm1 df ; this really makes me think it should all be done in dplry the first time...
                                                                                                                                                                                 Then I tried to create a new column in the tm1 df with the ratio

```
tm2$ratio <-tm2$x/tm1$x
```

and add in the ratio values only if the avg matches

```
df1$ratio <- tm2$ratio[match(tm2$x, df1$avg)]
```

This might work, but when I extract the avg values, it rounds, so the numbers do not match exactly. I'm also cautious about this because if I process ridiculous amounts of data, there's a higher and higher chance that two random averages will be similar enough to misplace these ratios.

I tried several other things that completely failed, so let's pretend that something worked and entered the ratio into the df1 as separate columns

Then any further calculations or annotations are straight forward:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
mutate(ratio = avg_tm2/avg_tm1,
lost = 1- ratio,
word = paste0(round(lost*100),"%"))
```

But I am still stuck on 'how' to call specific cells inside the pipe or which other tools/packages to use to calculate deltas or ratios between cells in the same column.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could group by 'trial' and `mutate` to create the 'ratio' column

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(trial) %>% 
   mutate(ratio = last(avg)/first(avg))
# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   trial [4]
#  time  trial   avg      var stdev ratio
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 time1 a     1815.  715630.  846. 0.795
#2 time1 b     2012. 1299823. 1140. 0.686
#3 time1 c     1505.  878168.  937. 1.09 
#4 time1 d     1387.  902364.  950. 1.17 
#5 time2 a     1444.  998943.  999. 0.795
#6 time2 b     1380.  720135.  849. 0.686
#7 time2 c     1641. 1205778. 1098. 1.09 
#8 time2 d     1619.  582418.  763. 1.17
```

NOTE: We used `set.seed(2)` for creating the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Work out a separate data.frame:

```
set.seed(2)
# your code above to generate df1
df2 <- select(df1, time, trial, avg) %>%
  spread(time, avg) %>%
  mutate(ratio = time2/time1)
df2
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#   trial    time1    time2     ratio
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     a 1815.203 1443.731 0.7953555
# 2     b 2012.436 1379.981 0.6857266
# 3     c 1505.474 1641.439 1.0903135
# 4     d 1386.876 1619.341 1.1676176
```

and now you can merge the relevant column onto the original frame:

```
left_join(df1, select(df2, trial, ratio), by="trial")
# Source: local data frame [8 x 6]
# Groups: time [?]
#    time trial      avg       var     stdev     ratio
#   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 time1     a 1815.203  715630.4  845.9494 0.7953555
# 2 time1     b 2012.436 1299823.3 1140.0979 0.6857266
# 3 time1     c 1505.474  878168.3  937.1063 1.0903135
# 4 time1     d 1386.876  902363.7  949.9282 1.1676176
# 5 time2     a 1443.731  998943.3  999.4715 0.7953555
# 6 time2     b 1379.981  720134.6  848.6074 0.6857266
# 7 time2     c 1641.439 1205778.0 1098.0792 1.0903135
# 8 time2     d 1619.341  582417.5  763.1629 1.1676176
```